# Android Collapsing Toolbar with navigation

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I want to implement a collapsing toolbar with navigation bar in it (dots). User can swipe over the image to go next image in the collapsing toolbar layout . How do I go with it?? I searched a lot many tutorials but I am able implement just collapsing toolbar layout. Many Thanks for any thoughts on it. [image: An example layout how I want it to be]

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
//actionbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow);

Toolbar actionbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
        if (null != actionbar) {
            actionbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow);

            actionbar.setTitle(R.string.title_activity_settings);
            actionbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   // your implementation here
                }
            });

            // Inflate a menu to be displayed in the toolbar
            actionbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
        }
```